# Ready for my rap album?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Initially, I played music, but after a spell,
they called me disreputable, I said "oh well"
The judge said I was out of order, but he was wrong,
I wasn't in at the beginning, but two places along

Is it inappropriate for me to to start something to eat?
I was just playing games, let me skip the repeat.
Look at me in the light, can't believe I'm so pretty
I guess I better go back to the Capital City

Hint One

> None of the lines requires any special knowledge except line 5, but the puzzle can be solved without that one. Lines 6 and 7 are not wordplay, all the rest are in the style of cryptic clues. Every line has a clue, but some clues go across lines. There are a couple instances of filler for the rhyme or the meter. The answer is very short.

Hint Two

> This might be easier for Gen X age-range people to figure out than other generations.

Hint Three

> If you're really really stuck on line 5, you might ask on English SE, I famously did! But probably not until after you solve the rest, unless you really want it handed to you on a platter.

Comment: +1 for the clever title!

Comment: Can we have a hint

Comment: @Deepthinker101 - Here's three, added above

Comment: This puzzle is harder than your other two. Also the title adds to the difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wild guess but is the word to you are looking CD?

Edit:

> Lines 1 and 2 maybe a HarpsiChorD. It was popular in the 17th century but was then replaced by the Piano.

Edit:

> 3 and 4 It is referring to OCD. The person in 4 sounds pedantic over where the I is located in line 3.

Edit:

> 5 I think it is referring to where Oliver Twist 'asked for more' in Charles Dickens' novel. The initials of Charles Dickens is CD.

Edit:

> 6 I think you are referring to ArCaDe

> 7 CDs look pretty if you shine light on it.

Edit:

> 8 On second thought maybe you are suggesting Washington 'DC'.

> Also CD fits with the title

Comment: Amazingly you got the answer right while only getting two of the clues correct --7 and the title.  I'm going to leave this open to see if anyone can get the correct references.

Comment: Line 8 is now correct, although you're either missing a key part of that clue or you just didn't list it. The other new explanations are impressive but wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Deepthinker101 has got the answer so here are what I *think* are some of the missing line explanations

Initially, I played music,

> CD are the initials for **C**ompact **D**isc whose primary use is to play music.
>  C and D are also musical notes.

but after a spell, they called me disreputable, I said "oh well"

> CD sounds like "seedy" (after a spell), meaning disreputable (I think "oh well" is filler).

The judge said I was out of order, but he was wrong,

> I think this refers to **DC** (CD out of order) which stands for either  **D**istrict **C**ourt or **D**efence **C**ounsel, but of course the judge is wrong because, really it is CD.

I wasn't in at the beginning, but two places along

> I think this refers to the beginning of the alphabet, so instead of starting *A,B,...* we start two places along at *C,D,...*

Is it inappropriate for me to to start something to eat?

> The something to eat here is "nuts" and is referring to the joke mentioned [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241081/origin-of-deez-nuts) on English Stack Exchange.

I was just playing games, let me skip the repeat.

> CDs are also used to hold games. CD "skipping" refers to a player not being able to read a faulty groove or block of data, one of the consequences of which is the CD playing a repeated section or track.
>  Skipping and repeating are also two *functions* of CD playing which were big improvements that the CD introduced on previous technologies (thanks to OP for clarifying).

Look at me in the light, can't believe I'm so pretty

> I think Deepthinker101 explained this adequately - the back of the CD reflects and refracts light to is very colourful and shiny.

I guess I better go back to the Capital City

> Deepthinker101 also effectively got this. CD "goes back" (reverses) to give **DC** (as in Washington DC, capital of the USA).

Comment: These are all essentially correct!  "After a spell" is the hint for line 2, and the key fact for line 3 is that the judge is wrong. Your line 6 explanation is good, but I'd also add that when these were first introduced, those two functions were a big part of their improvement over older technologies. Everything else is completely and correctly explained! :)

Comment: @ChrisSunamisupportsMonica Ah, I see what you mean, will add the clarifications.